# ¿Como puedo incluir alertify.js en un archivo .php?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Quisiera saber como puedo incluir el plugin http://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/ en un archivo .php, esto es lo que tengo hasta el momento:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../librerias/css/Login.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../librerias/responsive/GridLogin.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../librerias/responsive/MediaQueries_Login.css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../librerias/imagenes/Logo.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../librerias/css/animate.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <title>Iniciar Sesión</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="Titulo animated2 fadeIn">
   PSeInt+
  </div>
  <!--Formulario Login-->
  <hr class="HR1 animated2 fadeIn visible-sm visible-md visible-lg" color="black">
  <div class="Login animated2 fadeIn-1">
   <form class="Formulario" method="POST" action="../php/Login.php" id="Login">
    <div class="Container">
     <div class="input-group">
      <input type="email" name="correo" class="correo" placeholder="Correo" autocomplete="off" required />
     </div>
     <div class="input-group">
      <span id="change" class="eye"></span><input type="password" name="password" class="password" id="pass" placeholder="Contraseña" autocomplete="off" required />
     </div>
     <input type="submit" class="btn-submit" value="Iniciar Sesión" />
    </div>
   </form>
   <div class="Texto">
    ¿No tienes cuenta?
   </div>
   <div class="Texto2">
    <a href="Registro.html">Regístrate</a>
   </div>
  </div>
  <hr class="HR2 animated2 fadeIn visible-sm visible-md visible-lg" color="black">
  <!--Fin Formulario Login-->
  <div class="Texto3 animated2 fadeIn col-xs-12">
   Una ayuda más para fortalecer tu aprendizaje TIC
  </div>
  <script src="../js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/changeeye.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

```
<?php  
    include("Conexion.php");
    $cor = $_POST["correo"];
    $pass = $_POST["password"];
    $passEncriptado = md5($pass);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE correo='".$cor."' AND contrasena='".$passEncriptado."'";
    $resultado =  mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error");
    if (mysql_num_rows($resultado) > 0) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['usuSession'] = $cor;
        echo ' <script type="text/javascript"> 
            alert("Has iniciado sesión con éxito");
            window.location.href="../html/Index.php";
        </script>';
    } else {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript"> 
            alert("Correo o Contraseña incorrecta");
            window.location="../html/Login.html";
        </script> ';
    }
?>
```

Comment: usas jquery? o alguna otra biblioteca en Javascript? Por cierto, puedes agregar tambien la vista (el codigo completo en HTML)?? Tengo otra pregunta... como llamas a este código php ? desde un formulario?

Comment: SI uso jquery y llamo este codigo php desde el action de mi formulario

Answer (score 1):

Bueno.

La forma que usas para hacer el login no funciona bien con la biblioteca `alertify.js`. Alertify js funciona bien con peticiones asincronas (ajax en jquery).

Te recomiendo que uses peticiones asincronas, para las cuales debes desactivar el action del formulario y poner un código como el siguiente en JS (este es un ejemplo, pero hay bastante código en [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200266/submit-a-form-using-jquery)):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input#botonEnviar').click( function() {
        $.post( 'url_login', $('form#myForm').serialize(), function(data) {
               alertify.alert(data);
           },
           'json'
        );
    });
});
```

También [agregar los recursos](http://alertifyjs.com/guide.html) de alertify (cambiar segun tu caso):

```
<!-- include the script -->
<script src="{PATH}/alertify.min.js"></script>
<!-- include the style -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{PATH}/alertify.min.css" />
<!-- include a theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{PATH}/themes/default.min.css" />
```

Y devolver un mensaje desde el servidor [en formato json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064444/returning-json-from-a-php-script) o en texto plano, dependiendo de la configuración que tengas en la petición asíncrona.

La otra opción es que guardes los mensajes en la sesión y [redirijas a la vista](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php) correcta con `header('Location: '.$newURL);` desde php. no con `window.location.href` de javascript. Un ejemplo es mas o menos así (este tipo de mensajes sueles encontrarlos en internet como ["Flash messages"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28251555/store-error-message-in-session-and-display-on-another-page), aunque generalmente se usan dentro de un marco de trabajo. La gracia es que se guardan en la sesión y solo duran hasta la siguiente petición http):

```
if (mysql_num_rows($resultado) > 0) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['usuSession'] = $cor;
        header('Location: ../html/Index.php');
        exit;
    } else {
        $_SESSION['msg'] = 'El login ha fallado';
        header('Location: ../html/Login.html');
        exit;
}
```

entonces en tu vista de Login.php pones un código como el siguiente:

```
<form>
    <!-- mensaje de login -->
    <?php if(isset($_SESSION['msg'])) {
             echo $_SESSION['msg'];
             unset($_SESSION['msg']);
          } ?>
    <input>usuario</input>
    <input>contraseña</input>
</form>
```

Bueno. Esta es la idea, para que funcione tienes que elaborarla mas. Es de noche y por tiempo no te puedo escribir algo mas decente :(

(ojalá alguien edite esto para que funcione :P )

Answer (score 0):

No se si entendi bien tu pregunta pero puedes poner antes de abrir php

```
<script src="tucarpeta/alertify.min.js"></script>
```

o despues de cerrar ?>

```
<script src="tucarpeta/alertify.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacerlo como fue explicado en el otro comentario, yo lo hago de esta manera similar.

```
datos = "id_pago=" + id_pago;

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "eliminarpago.php",
            data: datos,
            success: function(data){
                if (data == 1) {
                    alertify.success("Se eliminó este pago");
                } else {
                    alertify.error("Error al eliminar")
                }
            }
        })
```

ya en tu archivo PHP podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
<?php 
include 'conexion.php';

$id = $_POST['id_pago'];

$sql = "DELETE FROM pagos WHERE id_pago = '$id'";

echo $resultado = $conexion->query($sql);

 ?>
```